# (gcloud.compute.ssh) Required 'compute.instances.get' permission

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am getting below error when trying to run build using triggers.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource: Info 2022-09-01T13:15:09.853777215Z - Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for 'projects/[]/zones/[]/instances/[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding anyone of the following role to the user/SA trying to ssh should fix your issue. There are more if you scroll down I just could not fit all the roles in screenshot. Check Logging to see which user/SA is trying to SSH.

[image]

Comment: how can I find which user/SA is being used? I tried to give permission but its not workin

Comment: I mentioned it already, in Logging. There should be a principal email you are looking for.